# 'invece di' vs. 'invece che' vs. 'piuttosto di' vs. 'piuttosto che'

Tags: grammar

Quoted from 'Pinocchio' by Collodi:

> Fatto sta che i tre torsoli, **invece di** essere gettati fuori dalla finestra, vennero posati sull'angolo della tavola in ...

Please, explain why Collodi uses **invece di** rather than 'invece che' vs. 'piuttosto di' vs. 'piuttosto che' and clarify whether these expressions, in that context, are interchangeable or not.

Answer (score 6):

Both pairs are interchangeable, that is

- *invece di* is equivalent to *invece che* (the former is more common, [La grammatica italiana](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/invece-di-o-invece-che_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/))
- *piuttosto di* is equivalent to *piuttosto che* (the latter is more common, while the former is mainly used in the phrases such as "Piuttosto di niente, è meglio piuttosto!" - "Better anything than nothing," [Grande dizionario italiano](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/p/piuttosto.aspx?query=piuttosto))

Answer (score 5):

I agree that the two forms are interchangeable.

Moreover, at least according to [Google nGram](http://goo.gl/p7JHWQ), *invece di* was more common during Collodi's times compared to *piuttosto che*.

I would generally avoid the usage of *piuttosto di* altogether (aside from the specific example cited by @I.M. and possibly a few more).